# Writing code to access agile octopus rest API in python 3 on a raspberry pi

Tags: python-3, password, curl

Octopus give an example of the command needed to access their API:

```
curl -u "sk_live_************************:" "https://api.octopus.energy/v1/products/AGILE-18-02-21/electricity-tariffs/E-1R-AGILE-18-02-21-M/standard-unit-rates/"
```

The ************************ represents what will be my password or unique key

My code is:

```
import urllib.request

curlplusurl = 'curl -u "sk_live_************************:" "https://api.octopus.energy/v1/products/AGILE-18-02-21/electricity-tariffs/E-1R-AGILE-18-02-21-M/standard-unit-rates/"'

with urllib.request.urlopen(curlplusurl) as response 
    answer = response.read()
```

I get the following error:

```
raise URLError('unknown url type: %s' % type)

urllib.error.URLError: urlopen error unknown url type: curl -u "sk_live_************************
```

the bit with the password/unique key is vital - so how do I give it if I can't do it the way Octopus describe?

Comment: Could you please edit the post using the code function - the important bit (where you build the URL) is split.  I would do this for you but its better if you do so the code can be checked by the author :-). Also - do you have a link to the API documentation from Octopus that you could include?

Answer (score 1):

To solve this you can use the download manager in the octopy-energy library (disclosure: which I've written) - https://ayrtonb.github.io/Octopy-Energy/

```py
from octopyenergy.api import DownloadManager

octopus_api_key = 'your_octopus_api_key'
meter_mpan = 'your_meter_mpan'
meter_serial = 'your_meter_serial'

download_manager = DownloadManager(meter_mpan=meter_mpan, 
                                   meter_serial=meter_serial, 
                                   api_key=octopus_api_key)

s_elec_consumption = download_manager.create_elec_consumption_s()

s_elec_consumption.plot()
```

[image]